# Changing the first element of a list in Python changes everyone else

Tags: python, list, debugging

Say I have the following class:

```py
class Elem():
    def __init__(self, valAcum=0, data=0, prev=0):
        self.valAcum = valAcum
        self.data = data
        self.prev = prev
```

And then, I do the following:

```py
D = [Elem()] * 3
D[0].data = 3
print(D) 
# [(0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 0)]
```

What is happening?
Doing `D[i].f = x` sets `f = x` in **every** element from D. Why is this happening? How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list has three references to the same `Elem` object. When you modify it, the change will be visible through all those reference since they all refer to the same object.

Instead, you should create three different objects. E.g.:

```py
D = [Elem() for _ in range(3)]
```